# How to avoid developing callus wearing vibrams with no socks?

Tags: running, vibram, callus

I have been jogging in Vibrams for over 8 months. I used to only do 2-3 miles in them, but have recently started doing 5 miles about 4 times a week. The forefoot of my right foot started developing callus, and it's not comfortable.
Is there a way to avoid the buildup or to deal with the uncomfortable feeling?

Comment: The FAQ (http://fitness.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) says to not ask questions like: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.” Perhaps you could rephrase this somehow? A question about how to avoid them, or how to deal with the problem would be on topic.

Comment: I edited Kates suggestion into the question. I think this way it might receive better answers. _"Is it normal?"_ could be answered by a simple _yes_ and I think that wouldn't suffice your issue. If you are unhappy with the changes feel free to revert them or edit again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> A callus (or [callosity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callosity)) is a toughened area of [skin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin) which has become relatively thick and hard in response to repeated friction, pressure, or other irritation.

<sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callus)</sup>

It is the defense reaction of your body, and, given the circumstances – running barefoot, in Vibram shoes – it's fully normal.

I don't know why are you running without socks, but if you want to harden your feet, then it's how it looks like. If you want to have soft skin, run in soft shoes with soft socks.

Comment: The reason is that the vibrams I have are of the perfect size. If i wore those toe socks, they would be too tight...But I guess if my feet will eventually become hardened and will not feel the discomfort, I have no problem with that..